# I am building a windows form app. How to collect all datagridviews from my app into a variable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a few datagridviews in my app and each should be filled with different information. So, I need a loop to go through all the gridviews. I tried this:

```
DataGridView[] gridViews = new DataGridView[50];
foreach(Control[] c in Controls)
{
    if(c is DataGridView[])
    {
        gridViews = ((DataGridView[])c);
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < gridViews.Length; i++)
{
    gridViews[i].Rows.Add(txtEmployeerName.Text, txtReferenceNumber.Text, txtPurchaseAmount.Text, txtPaymentDate.Text, txtPaymentAmount.Text, txtPartOne.Text, txtPartTwo.Text, txtPartThree.Text, txtPartFour.Text, txtPartFive.Text, txtRemainingDebt.Text);
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Did it work? What result are you expecting?

Comment: I recommend List<> instead of array, for easier adding and removing. You're close, keep going :)

Comment: It doesnt work, it shows me an error: Unable to cast object of type System.Windows.Forms.Button to type System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
List<DataGridView> gridViews = new List<DataGridView>();
foreach (Control c in Controls)
{
    if (c is DataGridView)
    {
        gridViews.Add((DataGridView)c);
    }
}
foreach (DataGridView dataGridView in gridViews)
{
    dataGridView.Rows.Add(txtEmployeerName.Text, txtReferenceNumber.Text, txtPurchaseAmount.Text, txtPaymentDate.Text, txtPaymentAmount.Text, txtPartOne.Text, txtPartTwo.Text, txtPartThree.Text, txtPartFour.Text, txtPartFive.Text, txtRemainingDebt.Text);
}
```

I changed the array to a generic list collection.  You werealso using DataGridview[] (array) as a type when it should have just been the control itself.

Comment: Thanks @ckojo.  One other point.. if this is actually how you are using it, you don't need the list.. just do the work in the Control c in Controls loop.  Good luck.